# PHP mail is empty when I send

Tags: php, function, email

When I send my mail with my PHP, the mail is empty, it's maybe because there is a probleme with the \r\n I think.
I don't have an idea to resolve this.

```
<?php

$mail = 'adrien.collery@gmail.com'; 
if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@(hotmail|live|msn).[a-z]{2,4}$#", $mail)) 
{
    $passage_ligne = "\r\n";
}
else
{
    $passage_ligne = "\n";
}

$message_txt = "Salut à tous, voici un e-mail envoyé par ";

$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());

$sujet = "Hey mon ami !";

$header = "From: \"AC\"<adrien.collery@gmail.com>".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "Reply-to: \"AC\" <adrien.collery@gmail.com>".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
$header .= "X-Priority: 3".$passage_ligne;
$header.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".$passage_ligne." boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;

$message = $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;

$message.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"".$passage_ligne;
$message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne.$message_txt.$passage_ligne;

$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary."--".$passage_ligne;
$message.= $passage_ligne."--".$boundary."--".$passage_ligne;   

var_dump(mail($mail,$sujet,$message,$header));


?>
```

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. use phpmailer or swiftmailer. it'll reduce all of that tedious mime stuff to a single call.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the à and the é in `$message_txt = "Salut à tous, voici un e-mail envoyé par ";` to see if this helps?

Comment: now why would that fix this? that isn't the problem

Comment: People may get upset if you ask them to misspell their language on the off chance that your site can't handle it.

Comment: I can't possibly see why this answer received an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your ----- from $boundary

```
$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());
```

Should look like his

```
$boundary = md5(rand();
```

and remove $passage_ligne after Content-Type value.

```
$header.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".$passage_ligne." boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;
```

Should look like this:

```
$header.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;
```

Comment: Thank you but the content of the mail is yet empty